# How do I compress data in an Azure Logic App to send in an email?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple logic app that runs a daily SQL report, converts the data into a CSV, then attaches the CSV to an email.  (see image)

[image]

The problem is, that the data is getting too big for the email server to allow.  So, if I can compress the CSV, or convert it to an XLS, it'll be small enough for the email server to handle it.

Can I get this done without writing to blob storage or any other storage system?  I did find a 3rd party action by Encodian which I might be able to use, just can't figure out the details.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get this done without writing to blob storage or any other storage system? I did find a 3rd party action by Encodian which I might be able to use, just can't figure out the details.

You can use encodian's Convert Excel Action.

[image]

In order to set up the connection, you need to add the API key choosing the Encodian subscription that fits your needs and budget.

[image]

For more information, you can refer [Encodian Flowr for Azure Logic Apps](https://www.encodian.com/products/flowr/#form)

Alternatively, You can use Plumsail's Csv to Excel action.

[image]

while adding the connector you can generate an API key from [Plumsail Account API Key](https://account.plumsail.com/documents/api-keys).

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Convert Excel and CSV Files](https://www.encodian.com/blog/convert-excel-and-csv-files-in-power-automate/)
2. [How to convert CSV files to Excel](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/convert-csv-to-excel-in-power-automate-flow.html)